# Linq to SQL available in Xamarin?

Tags: linq-to-sql, xamarin

Can you use LINQ to SQL in Xamarin?

I want to query a SQL Server DB (not SQLite), and want to know if LINQ is an option.

Comment: In which case do you need that? You really want to open a raw port of SQL Server for an app on mobile network to access it? That's a horrible design from all aspects.

Comment: Well, let say I want to display the top 10 clients for this quarter on a mobile page.  Why is LINQ a horrible design?  What else should I use - SqlDataReader?

Comment: Check the answer below. LINQ is fine, but you can never leave your database open directly like that.

Comment: Thanks and noted.  But for the sake of completeness, I think it would be good if we can still get a definite Yes, or No answer on the question.  I know the real answer is that it's not a good idea, but whether it's possible will be good to know.

Answer (score 1):

It is not considered a good design to make the database available through the internet for several reasons. Instead you should think about writing a web service that your app consumes and operates on. This way you gain more control of the actions that should be done on your database.

Comment: Thanks. I assume the reasons you refer to is mostly security?  I will look towards the web services, but still would like to know if linq will work at all.  Even though I might not use it.

Comment: Are there any other viable options besides web services?  WCF perhaps?

Comment: LINQ in general will work. If it includes LINQ to SQL, I don't know. WCF is not fully implemented in MONO. There are some known issues with the automatic proxy generation. Especially on iOS because of there AOT compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your data via a web service. (which can use linq to sql or entity framework)

After you have it in your app, you can use a sqlite database in your app to store it and operate on it locally with linq to sql.

At this point you do need a way to synchronizes the local and server database.

This way you can provide offline access to your app.